# Removing Header from Chapter in a Thesis Written in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, thesis

I am writing a thesis using the `LaTeX` template files that seem to have been used at my department for a while. The problem is, when I compile the code, I get a header with chapter number and title on the page where chapter 2 starts.

[image: Chapter 2 Title and Header]

It doesn't happen though on the page where chapter 1 begins.

[image: Chapter 1 Title and Header]

I want to remove the header from the start page of chapter 2 but despite trying a lot, I could not figure out what is causing it to appear there (and not on start page of chapter 1) and how to get rid of it. Will appreciate any help. Here is the MWE for the main `LaTeX` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

% Page number must be in the upper righthand corner
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{phdthesis}{
\fancyhf{} %clear all headers and footers fields
\rhead{\thepage} %prints the page number on the right side of the header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 }
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{phdthesis}}

% to remove page numbers on empty pages (before chapter start)
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

 %% TITLE PAGE AND DECLARATION
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \begin{titlepage}
 \end{titlepage}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %% CONTENTS
 \tableofcontents

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %% CHAPTERS
 \newpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}

 %% INCLUDE TEXT OF CHAPTER 1 IN THE FILE chp1.tex 
 \include{chp1}

 %% INCLUDE TEXT OF CHAPTER 2 IN THE FILE chp2.tex 
 \include{chp2}

 %% INCLUDE TEXT OF CHAPTER 3 IN THE FILE chp3.tex 
 \include{chp3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Here is the code for all the 3 chapters which are saved separately as chp1.tex, chp2.tex and chp3.tex in the same directory:

```
\chapter{{\it Chapter 1 Title}}\label{chp1}
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
{\it Text for Chapter \ref{chp1}}

\chapter{{\it Chapter 2 Title}}\label{chp2}
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
{\it Text for Chapter \ref{chp2}}

\chapter{{\it Chapter 3 Title}}\label{chp3}
\thispagestyle{myheadings}
{\it Text for Chapter \ref{chp3}}
```

Please help.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue using your code. Maybe there  is a `\pagestyle{fancy}` before the chapters. Remove `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` after the `\chapter` commands. Then pagestyle `plain` is used on the chapter pages. Off topic: `\it` is deprecated for a long time and do not use font commands inside the argument of sectioning commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to look at my problem. Commenting out `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` after `\chapter` command worked for the header on chapter 2 start page but there was no `\pagestyle{fancy}` before the chapters. I don't understand but I very much want to, why it was this way? When I comment out `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` from chapter 2 LaTeX file, the header goes away but the same command appears on LaTex files for chapter 1 and 3 too and there no header appears whether or not I comment out this command. There's really no significant chunk of code that I didn't show here.

Comment: @esdd, you said you can't reproduce the issue using my code. Can I do something to make it more reproducible? All I want to do is it to understand why `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` command on chapter 2 start page creates a header but the same command does not do it for chapter 1 and 3.

Comment: Test your code example in a new folder. Then you can see what we get. There could also be a `\pagestyle{phdthesis}` or `\pagestyle{plain}` in your real code. Note that your code redefines plain using `\fancypagestyle`. They all activate the automatic setting of a `\leftmark` by \chapter and cleaning `\rightmark`. I am sure that your issue does not depend on the chapter number, but on the page number. You will get header entries only on even chapter pages, but not on odd chapter pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @esdd. You were right, I tested the code with 4 chapters and this time I got headers on chapters 2 and 4 (which start on even pages), but not on chapters 1 and 3 (which begin on odd pages). I checked my complete code and found that just before table of contents, there is a page for disclaimer and there `\pagestyle{phdthesis}` does appear. So you are are right in all cases. I work almost all the time with article class. Here, why does this `\pagestyle{phdthesis}` class produce headers on odd pages? I looked at how it was defined in the document preamble but could not figure it.

Comment: The first call of `\pagestyle` with a `fancyhdr` pagestyle enables `\chapter` to set `\leftmark` and clean `\rightmark`. Pagestyle `myheadings` uses `\leftmark` on even pages and `\rightmark` on odd pages. Because `\chapter` cleans the content of `\rightmark` there is no header entry on your odd chapter pages. But  even chapter pages with pagestyle `myheadings` uses `\leftmark` and therefore get the chapter title in header. So you have to remove `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` after the `\chapter` commands.

Comment: Thank you so much, @esdd. I understand it now. I should have come here earlier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\thispagestyle{myheadings}` after the `\chapter` commands.

Then your own pagestyle `phdthesis` will be used on chapter pages, because of

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{phdthesis}}
```